# php merge image with it own fliped and rotated view at different positions

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

i want to  merge image with it own flipped image and rotated at angle say -60 degree.

Suppose i  have image of 1000*1000 px then
A: original image resized to 500*500px and places in right bottom part of 1000*1000 square box
B:same image a flipped and rotated by -600 degree and place in top left corner of 1000*1000 square box

everything works fine but just issue like
**1: some border for rotated images**
**2: background on rotate one is more darker make it look bid odd**

**test case :**

**sample image** (thumbnail is resized, click to open original image) :

> [image]

**output image** :

> [image]

**Below is my code**

```
$image1=$image2=imagecreatefrompng('a.png');
//filter_opacity( $image1, 25 );

$w=imagesx($image1);
$h=imagesy($image1);


$finala = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$finalb = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$finalc = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

$backgroundColora = imagecolorallocate($finala, 250,252,252); // gray
$backgroundColorb = imagecolorallocate($finalb, 250,250,250); // gray
$backgroundColorc = imagecolorallocate($finalc, 250,250,250); // gray

imagefill($finala, 0, 0, $backgroundColora);
imagefill($finalb, 0, 0, $backgroundColorb);
imagefill($finalc, 0, 0, $backgroundColorc);


$percent = 0.583;
$new_width = $w * $percent;
$new_height = $h * $percent;
$wshift = $w/8.5;
$hshift = $h/2.5;


imagecopy($finala, $image1, 0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagecopyresampled($finala, $image2,$wshift,$hshift,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
imagecopy($finalc, $image1, 0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagecopyresampled($finalc, $image2,$wshift,$hshift,0,0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($finalb, $finalc,$w*0.3,$h*0.3,0,0, $w*0.6, $h*0.6, $w, $h);
imageflip($finala, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL );
$finala = imagerotate($finala, -60, imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagecopyresampled($finalb, $finala,-$w*0.1,-$h*0.1,0,$h*0.20, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($finalb);
imagedestroy($finala);
imagedestroy($image2);
imagedestroy($image1);
imagedestroy($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to rotate and place same image at top and bottom, you no need to pass same image twice with $_GET single time is enough

```
// Source image
$image = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
$w=imagesx($image);
$h=imagesy($image);
$finalImage = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

// Bg add
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 252,252,252); // gray
imagefill($finalImage, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);

// New sizes calculation
$percent = 0.5;
$new_width = $w * $percent;
$new_height = $h * $percent;

// First image add
imagecopyresampled($finalImage, $image, $new_width, $new_height, 0, 0,
                   $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);

// Second image rotate with transparant bg
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha( $image,0,0,0,127 );
$rotatedImage = imagerotate( $image, -60, $transparency, 1);
imagealphablending( $rotatedImage, false );
imagesavealpha( $rotatedImage, true );

// Getting new rotated image sizes to avoid cutting border
$rw = imagesx($rotatedImage);
$rh = imagesy($rotatedImage);

// Second rotated image add with bigger space
imagecopyresampled($finalImage, $rotatedImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   $rw*$percent, $rh*$percent, $rw, $rh);
// Outputing png image 
header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
imagepng( $finalImage );
```

Comment: actually i did not got the issue with that border, bot images fully feet inside content noting is out what is problem ? can you attach more detailed screenshot

Comment: this is the result which i got at my side http://s17.postimg.org/pbv2fh526/download.jpg no border or something displayed, can you send your result and highlight there your problem ?

Comment: here is my example: http://imgur.com/iwWX7vm, at my side rotation angle was `90 degree` but seems at your side it is `60 degree` ? can it be that your image has border ?

Comment: I see in your example that top left corner image rotated in 60 degree not 90 degree can you confirm that `$rotatedImage = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);` is called with `-90` param and not `-60` at your side ?

Comment: you are using there `-60` which mean rotate by 60 degree and because of that you are having  problem with border, if you use exactly my example code you will fully get result image like this: http://imgur.com/iwWX7vm where provided image placed at right bottom corner and rotated by 90degree at left top corner. Isn't it what you are looking for in your question ?

Comment: then you need to change degree to `-60` or `-120` and additionally you will have problem with transparency during rotation to solve it here is detailed answer about how to rotate with transparent bg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540231/rotate-a-png-then-resave-with-image-transparency where you just need to pass $transparency during rotation

Comment: i tested your code it working totally wrong i got same image placed twice at same place: http://s8.postimg.org/5l7iy3wol/wrong.jpg, i updated my code in answer which produce what you need: http://s16.postimg.org/6428a6tzp/correct.png , i would suggest you rewrite your code or copy past code from answer and make additional changes which you need

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
$finala = imagerotate($finala, -60, imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 0, 0, 0, 127));
```

to

```
$finala = imagerotate($finala, -60, imageColorAllocateAlpha($finala, 250, 252, 252, 127));
```

the black board should gone!

Comment: can u tell what it does

Comment: @saurav it matches your finala's backgroundColora.