# PHP remove a section of image leaving a transparent space

Tags: php

I have an transparent image with a bar through the middle...
http://i66.tinypic.com/2zyeg4h.png

Using php I would like to remove the middle part on the bar, leaving a transparent space in the middle of the bar. I try this code...

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('****root****/image.png');
//make a yellow box
$transparent = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 0);
//make the yellow box transparent
imagecolortransparent($im, $transparent);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 200, 115, 300, 137, $transparent);

imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

header ('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);

$save = "****root****/test.png";
imagepng($im, $save);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

But the output image has the rectangle retain the yellow colour, rather than turn it transparent.

http://i67.tinypic.com/1ny6j4.png

Where am I going wrong? If I remove...

```
 imagealphablending($im, false);
 imagesavealpha($im, true);
```

I get the transparent box in the center (in the browser), but the rest of the image loses it's transparency and has a white background instead, also when I download that image and open in a photo editor, the transparency box in the center is gone. I have GD libraries set up on my server.

Comment: 127 is the correct value for 100% opacity. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540231/rotate-a-png-then-resave-with-image-transparency/13540666#13540666

Comment: Hi Michel, thanks for the reply, I tried... $transparent = imageColorAllocateAlpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);    .... but now the bar doesn't get affected. The output is like the original image ... http://i66.tinypic.com/2zyeg4h.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the gd function `imagecolorallocatealpha` to create a transparent color.

You could generate the whole image with PHP.

e.g.

```
<?php
// generate empty image
$image = imagecreate(500, 262);

// define black
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

// create left part of the bar
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 110, 200, 162, $black);

// create right part of the bar
imagefilledrectangle($image, 300, 110, 500, 162, $black);

// save image
imagepng($image, 'outimage.png');
```

[image: outimage.png]

If you want to stick with an existing image

```
<?php
// generate empty image
$image = imagecreatefrompng('input.png');

// define transparent
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 127);

// create the transparent area
imagefilledrectangle($image, 200, 110, 300, 162, $transparent);

// save image
imagepng($image, 'output.png');
```

input.png

[image: input.png]

output.png

[image: output.png]

You don't need to send a header if you're not submitting the image as a result to a browser.

e.g.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

Would display the image in the requesting browser rather than saving it to a file.

Comment: Hi Michel, thanks so much for you help! I tried your code using the existing image, though the output file doesn't seem to have the transparent rectangle cut out the bar, image looks the same... http://i66.tinypic.com/2zyeg4h.png . I also tried a solid black image as the input, but it just outputs the same solid black image, no transparent rectangle cut out. Why would the code not work for me?

Comment: The first script pasted exactly like your's outputs a solid black image 500x 262px, no transparency for me.

Comment: If you execute the example here, do you get the example image? http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php

Comment: Which PHP/GD version and which OS are you using?

Comment: From gd_info() ...

array(12) { ["GD Version"]=> string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)" ["FreeType Support"]=> bool(true) ["FreeType Linkage"]=> string(13) "with freetype" ["T1Lib Support"]=> bool(false) ["GIF Read Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Create Support"]=> bool(true) ["JPEG Support"]=> bool(true) ["PNG Support"]=> bool(true) ["WBMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["XPM Support"]=> bool(true) ["XBM Support"]=> bool(true) ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=> bool(false) } 

Current PHP version: 5.4.452.0

Linux CENTOS 6.8

Comment: I get the same example image as displayed on php.net on my server

Comment: Hi Michel, your script 100% works :) The issue was with the input image I was using, I needed to set it to indexed color mode from RGB in Photoshop and everything works perfectly. I'm incredibly grateful for your help, thank you so much!!