# PHP GD draw shape over another shape and make it transparent

Tags: php, drawing, transparency, gd

I am working on a charting library, and i use GD to draw the charts and gauges. This all works great, but i would like to have the possibility of a transparent background. I finally got that working, but now i come across a new question.

To draw complex gauges, i draw multiple shapes over each other. Like when i need a donut pie chart, i draw a regular pie chart - and then i draw a center ellipse, giving the impression of being a donut. This works great when there is a background color like white, or any other color. When using a transparent background, this draws the pie and everything as it should - i draw the donut center, but i cant turn the center to transparent.

Pie Chart:
[image: Pie Chart]

Donut Chart:
[image: Donut Chart]

I cant get the center (white) to be transparent, i dont want to draw the center with alpha transparency as the pie would shine through - but i want to replace the white with transparent pixels.

I tried `imagecolortransparent($image, $white);` but cant get it to work. Anyone that can point me in the right direction, or possibly can tell me if it is possible at all.

Comment: Difficult without seeing any code, but looks similar to the idea in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628125/php-remove-a-section-of-image-leaving-a-transparent-space

Comment: I got it partially working by filling the center white, and then `imagefill($this->image->image, $x, $y, $this->image->background->color);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, might come in handy for other people having the same issue. I draw the center with a solid color, and then do a imagefill at the center of the shape. I fill this with a truecolor with alpha transparency set to 127. This replaces the (in my case white) pixels with pixels set to full transparency.

[image: Pie]
[image: Radial Pie]

At the creation i use `imagecreatetruecolor` and i set `imagesavealpha($image, true)`. I **dont** set `imagealphablending($image, false)` because it will cause other colors with Alpha to completely remove the background (like indicators in the donut in the question).