# GDLibrary: the edges of rotated image becomes zigzag

Tags: php, gd

I'm using GD Library to rotate my image but the edges of rotated image becomes zigzag. How to make the edges smooth with GD?
I know there is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4804969
but it does not work.

```
<?php
$filename       = '2.png';
$degrees        = 10;

$im = imagecreatefrompng( $filename );
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha( $im,0,0,0,127 );

$rotated = imagerotate( $im, $degrees, $transparency, 1);

imagealphablending( $rotated, false );
imagesavealpha( $rotated, true );


header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
imagepng( $rotated );
imagedestroy( $im );
imagedestroy( $rotated );
?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imageantialias.php ?

Comment: @bZezzz can you share the working code? i tried with imageantialias and the result still same my posted image.

Comment: GImme your original image I'll reproduce, but maybe depends of your image quality, with large image no "zigzag" appear/

Comment: @bZezzz i update my original image on first post. please check it. thank you! i have tried with large image 1890x1494 px, it still have zigzag

Comment: After testing, same problem, image resolution too small.